# htaccess redirect all to https to http except for one folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, facebook-opengraph

I don't know why I can't find this or do this but basically all I want to do is redirect any page on my server to https:// unless it is in the folder /fbthumbnails/ because facebook doesn't allow thumbnails to be https://.

Comment: and how would you like todo that, php or apache, your tags arent clear. and what in the heck has facebook todo with it ?

Comment: haha fb doesn't let you pick ssl images for the opengraph og:image.  Funny huh.  And I'm doing it in htaccess

Answer (score 11):

Using mod_rewrite, stick this in an appropriate place in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fbthumbnails/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

Change the `R` to `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect.

Comment: My fault that did work I just needed to put the full url /wp-content/themes/wisewordsfromwoo/images/fbthumbnails/

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it includes the http for the condition?

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` checks that it's *not* http:// but it's possible that wordpress may be doing something that messes with tat.