# Force only admin to use HTTPS in CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter app and I want to force only the admin to use HTTPS connection and the single users have to use HTTP.

I have another folder in the controller folder for the admin's controllers so I tried to redirect every request which is contain the server name or server IP address and the admin in the URL. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^/admin/(.*) - [C]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It should redirect every request to the http site, which doesn't contain the  `admin` expression int the URI, but is not working and still using HTTPS. My base url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://127.0.0.1';
```

And I want this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/blog for users
https://127.0.0.1/admin/blog/addnew for admin
```

Comment: Why not allow your non-admin users to use HTTPS? It doesn't hurt to give non-admins extra privacy too.

Comment: I know, I would like to build a vulnerable app, where the users can practice the MitM attacks, but I want to protect the admin.

Comment: Nice idea. I think this question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753987/htaccess-redirect-all-to-https-to-http-except-for-one-folder

Comment: There's nothing wrong with lettings everyone using HTTPS, though you could simply do this in the core controller of CI itself aswell. Just check if the current user has admin rights, if not, redirect to http, if he does has the rights, redirect to https?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Apache magician, but this *should* work -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [QSA,L]
```

Source: [htaccess redirect all to https to http except for one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753987/)