# Redirecting from http to https using htaccess except for certain subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, mod-rewrite

I recently learned that Godaddy provides a code for their customers who purchased their SSL certificate to redirect http to https using htaccess file.  The code is shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, there are about 10 subdirectories that I do not wish to redirect.  What would be the most efficient way to exclude those directories?

Also, is the code above compatible with Cloudflare's CDN?  I learned that some loops might occur.  Thanks

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753987/htaccess-redirect-all-to-https-to-http-except-for-one-folder

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use this, just place the directories that you do not want to be `HTTPs` inside the brackets:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force everything to HTTPs
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#Checks if HTTPs is on for foobar & foobar2, if it is, turn it off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(foobar|foobar2)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can obviously add as many directories as you like to this, just separate them with `|`.

Comment: It did not work.  It shows "too many loops" when I tried to visit the website as well as the subdirectories